# No Bandwidth on long custom lan cable or no connection at all

Tags: networking, sftp, cable

i have two CAT7 SFTP cable (around 40m long) and two problems. First Cable (12):

```
Router 
 |
 v
1gbps switch --> cat8.1 patch cable --> cat6A keystone jack --> ~40m cat7 SFTP cable --> cat6A keystone jack --> cat8.2 patch cable --> wifi6 AP
```

Switch says:  cable is OK - Estimated cable length is 27.00 - 51.00 m

```
Bandwidth:
100mbps HDX  --> ~80 mbps down / ~90 mbps up / ping ~7ms
100mbps FDX  --> ~20 mbps down / ~20 mbps up / ping ~10ms   (connected, a lot of drops and errors like >500 errors per min on max mbps)
1gbps   FDX  --> ~ 0 mbps down / ~0  mbps up / ping ~9999ms (no connection, no drops, no errors)
```

I checked the cable today with a HT Quicklan 6055 and connections a OK.

Two days ago i had an old POE+ AP running on 1gbps (3W, no drops, no errors) on this connection / cable. I changed it to the new wifi6 AP first with POE+ ~7W and it didn't want to connect with 1gbps. I changed back to the old AP and it didn't work on 1gbps since then.

I guess i have to change the cable to Cat 8.1 SFTP and the keystone jacks to cat8 ones the next days. I wired the cable every time
according to 568 A.

Its a duplex cable, the other one is connected with my computer (same connector types) and it works with 1gbps. The AP connected directly to the switch with one short Cat7 cable delivers 350mbps with no problem.

**Could it be an twisted pair wiring problem?
And is there a difference in bandwidth between POE+ (on / off) on this cable length?
Is it recommended to keep POE+ off and use a power adapter where possible?**

I am grateful for any ideas!

For my second cable (13):

Same setup as mentioned above, except for the end. There is a adaptor like [this one](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07HKQR9YP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). I checked the cable with the HT Quicklan 6055 and the cable is OK. But switch says:

```
cable is not OK
Failure is located approximately 7.00 - 28.00 m from the switch.
        Pair A          Pair B          Pair C          Pair D
Length  7.00 - 27.00 m  8.00 - 28.00 m  7.00 - 27.00 m  8.00 - 28.00 m
State   ✗               ✗               ✗               ✗
```

Same wire was running with passiv poe for two years. Changed to new AP with 1gbps POE+, a new connector (as linked) at the end of Cat7 SFTP and the leds on the switch remains off.

**What could be the reason that the cable are connected properly but the switch sees an error on every (cable) pair?**

Comment: All your doing with your tester is checking the wiremap, that means basically nothing to verify you put the right color in the right spot... Are these patch cables or infrastructure? If infrastructure, terminate them on real JACKS that are quality like Panduit or Leviton and use patch cables on either end... And you don't make patch cords, by pre-tested, certified patch cords. Gigabit, 10GB, POE+, etc are all very susceptible to minor cable issues that would work find in simple 100Mbps applications.

Comment: This comment was going in the right direction I guess. I exchanged cat7 awg 23 cable with cat8.1 awg22 cable and the lan plugs with crimped ones. Now it runs 1 gbps with POE+ no problems. The linked lan plugs are trash, 100mbps max if they work. Most time the switch will say connection is not ok but cable tester will say everything is fine. For my patchpannel i use cat8 and cat6a keystone jacks (dont realy know the manufacturer) but these run fine with 1 gbps. I couldnt find Pandulin / Leviton with cat7/8 ratings...

Comment: FWIW... All this Cat-7, Cat-8, etc... All mean nothing when you are operating at 1Gbps. TBH, anything above Cat-5e/Cat-6 is not going to improve your performance at those speeds, so save your money and buy quality over "performance" in this case. One thing I can tell you is the higher end you get in cables, the more susceptible they are to minor issues, whereas you damn near wrap a CAT-5e cable around a flourescent light and then kink it 180 degrees and it will still work at a 1Gb, Do that with a cable costing 10 times as much and you might not even get a link. (I am exaggerating, kind of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to acejavelin, i figuered out it was a quality problem.

First Cable (12):

I exchanged CAT7 AWG23 cable with CAT8.1 AWG22 cable. At the patch pannel i used keystone CAT8.1 jacks (Logi Link) and at the other end crimped lan plugs or CAT6a jacks. Now 1 gbps arent a thing any more. The Problem was bad cable quality for a long cable and some kinks. POE+ isnt a problem for this cable length.

Second cable (13):

[I tested these typ of lan plug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaTB3.png)

Never ever use these typ of adapters. They sell it with cat8 ratings, but realistic you will only get 100mbps if you are lucky. I use crimped ones and these are 100 times better and they are cheaper.